# SOLR - indexing million of rows of data from Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing, solr

I want to index a table containing millions of rows of data in a postgre sql server.What would be the better way to do it..indexing from the database directly using data import handler or by dumping the data into a csv first and then indexing that csv file which is stored locally and why?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer indexing from database directly.
I would have taken below approach.

1. Create the partitions in the existing database. You can create partitions of  on 6 months or 3 months or of a year. It all depends on your requirement.
   This will help you to retrieve the data from database faster for solr.
2. Then you add the query in data-config.xml to retrieve the data for solr and index the data. You can index the data in small chunks and when there is less load on the application database. Preferably you should do the indexing nightly.

The other advantage of partitioning the database is, it would help you to retrieve the data for the other part of the application.

I would not prefer the second approach because it be time consuming. Get the data in csv files and then add to solr for indexing.

The other problem is converting to csv files is of no use to us, so why to invest time into it.

If by chance your data gets modified, it will not reflect in the csv file.

Comment: I tried indexing from database directly..it took around 40 minutes to index 1 million rows..I have around 8 million rows ...is this time acceptable? because I think it is very slow and will put a lot of load on the server for around 4-5 hours.Is there any other way to index it faster?

Comment: yes it will take time. Have you tried doing partition and suing it for your data-config query? Did you find any difference than earlier? To avoid the load on the server you can index the same in offline hours. You can schedule it nighly...check if that is possible for you.

Comment: I tried by converting to csv..it is taking much less time...5 minutes to take a dump from database to a csv ... then divided the 7.3 gb file to many 500 mb chunks..it is taking 4 minutes to index one 500 mb file..so overall I think it  will take around 1 hour..isn't it better? Because it is taking less time to index and it will not give load on the server... I am not trying to give counter arguments, I am just trying  to understand.Thanks.

Comment: oh really...then it would be the best option for you...I didnt tried it...In that case you should opt for the second option...My only worry is how would you manage any change in the database record... you need to update the changes later...